# Multi-file search in vim

Tags: macos, vim, full-text-search

I am comfortable with vim for normal editing.

I still need to use BBEdit for a few things. Mainly multi-file search. I provide it a folder listing of XCode project and what I want to search for and it produces a listing of files that I can do down through and do whatever.

http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.02/BBEditDoesntSuck/figure3.jpg

Can I somehow do this in vim? I am using the new `maximum-awesome` version released by Square: https://github.com/square/maximum-awesome

Answer (score 4):

Given that maximum-awesome includes the ack plugin and the silver searcher package, `:Ack string` is the easiest way to do this. It also includes unimpaired plugin, so you can navigate the results (in clist) using `[q` and `]q`. `:help unimpaired`, `:help ack`.

Comment: You can also invoke the `:Ack` shortcut using `,a`.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: I just read through the plugin source as well as the plugin documentation, and there's only commands, no maps. I'd bet the map is yours. EDIT: I just saw you're maintainer of maximum awesome, so I'd guess it's a map that is defined there; I just thought it's important to point out to whoever finds this answer that it is not Ack's binding by default.

Comment: Ah, yep, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use that silly distribution, it may feel like a convenient shortcut at first but it will slow you down. Configuring Vim and installing plugins *yourself* according to *your* needs is a large part of the learning experience. Skip that part and you'll be hooked to plugins and to someone else's tastes without getting the chance to actually learn to use Vim.

Case in point:

- Vim does exactly what you want without plugins.

  ```
  :vim foo **/*.m | cw
  ```

  searches for `foo` in every `*.m` file under the working directory and opens the quickfix window if matches are found.

  See `:help file-searching` and `:h :vim grep`.
- You have installed a distribution that comes with 35 plugins without even reviewing them and deciding if they are worth installing or not or even actually read up on what they do. One of those plugins, Ack.vim, is there specifically to provide a streamlined (and fast) project-wide search experience. You should read its documentation, `:help ack`.

  And, maybe, try the standard method before you get too used to Ack.vim.

Comment: You make some good points here. It can be very beneficial to learn the ins and outs of exactly what vim is doing when using plugins. And your point about making sure the plugins installed are needed is good. However, not *everyone* necessarily wants this, so calling maximum-awesome (or Janus, or whatever) "silly" is probably unfair. Full disclosure, I help maintain maximum-awesome.

Comment: Wow, that last sentence is scary. You maintain a distribution without knowing how to do multi-file search *and* knowing what the plugins in that distrib do. Not everyone wants "this" but everyone needs this. Big difference.

Comment: I didn't say that I didn't know, only that not *everyone* need know. Clearly we disagree on that, though.

Comment: @BrianDonovan, sorry, I confused you with the asker. My point remains, though: in order to become an efficient user, new vimmers *must* learn the low level stuff before getting to the high level stuff and not delude themselves into thinking they are using Vim while they are in fact using your crappy distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vimg for multi file search.

```
vimg /search string/ **

** makes it recursive for all file types

**/**.java if you want to search recursively for all java files

* if you want to search current working directory only
```

copen to open search results

cnext to see next match

cprev to see prev match

cclose to close search results